# Hilbert scheme of Lefschetz fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $\pi:E\to\mathbb{C}$ be a Lefschetz fibration where $E_0$ is the singular fiber over $0\in\mathbb{C}$. In the case when $E$ is a smooth complex surface, Donaldson & Smith proved that, the relative Hilbert scheme ($n$-points on the same fiber) $Hilb^n(E,\pi)$ is still smooth and $\pi^{[n]}:Hilb^n(E,\pi)\to\mathbb{C}$ is a nodal degeneration with the singular fiber over $0\in\mathbb{C}$.

I wonder if there is any extension to $Hilb^2(E,\pi)$ for $E$ of higher dimension (here $n=2$ since $Hilb^2(X)$ is always smooth for smooth $X$ in any dimension). If there is not, could anyone show some counterexample?